# Auxiliary for the verb "passer"

Tags: grammaire, passé-composé

We know some of the "movement verbs" need to change back to use *avoir* in compound tenses if there is a direct object after the verb. For this case, which one is correct?

> 1. J'ai passé la rue.
> 2. Je suis passé la rue.

Answer (score 7):

*Passer* can have many different meanings and denote different types of movements, which will dictate what is the auxiliary and preposition to use.

The most common usage would be *passer* as "to go/walk/drive" (in a street). Then you will use the auxiliary *être* and a preposition:

> Je suis passé dans la rue et je t'ai vu, tu promenais ton chien.

Note that you can also use then the preposition *par* if you want to stress that the street was just a step on the way to a destination.

> La rue Dupont était bloquée, alors je suis passé par la rue Durand pour arriver place de la République.

*Passer* can also mean "to skip" also as part of an itinerary or a movement, and in that case, you need to use the auxiliary *avoir* (and no preposition):

> Le parking était dans la troisière rue à gauche: j'ai passé les deux premières rues, et j'ai ensuite pris la troisième rue comme indiqué.

Comment: Je ne sais pas s'il cela vaut un commentaire, ni si cela peut aider, mais passer + avoir peut également se comprendre comme "passer par/à travers" (pass through). Même si "passer la rue" veut dire qu'on l'a "skip", "passer la porte" veut dire qu'on est passé à travers. Est-ce utile à l'OP ? Je ne sais pas, et si non, alors on pourra supprimer mon commentaire.